# animation buttons

Tags: animation, keyframes

[image]

At the bottom of the screen I can usually see the play button and the start and end frame numbers of the animation but on here they have gone and in order to play I need to press the space bar. However I want to jump to a specific frame number and they have gone.
Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

Click on the tiny down-arrow indicated below to bring back the header line.
[image]